# How to read other files in hadoop jobs?

Tags: python, hadoop

I need to read in a dictionary file to filter content specified in the `hdfs_input`, and I have uploaded it to the cluster using the `put` command, but I don't know how to access it in my program.

I tried to access it using path on the cluster like normal files, but it gives the error information: IOError: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Besides, is there any way to maintain only one copy of the dictionary for all the machines that runs the job ?

So what's the correct way of access files other than the specified `input` in hadoop jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the file needed with the `-file` option or `file=` option in conf file.